# How to do a zebra table with rowspans

Tags: html, css, html-table

This CSS code

```
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background:#eee;
}
```

or this JS+CSS code

```
$("tr:odd").addClass("odd");

.odd {
   background: #ccc;
}
```

produce this zebra table effect:

[image]

But how does one achieve the following zebra table effect?

[image]

Some sample code here: https://jsfiddle.net/61bup2Lr/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use nth-child for styling with a table with rowspan?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200997/how-to-use-nth-child-for-styling-with-a-table-with-rowspan)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. That OP has a specific problem: "It's like if I see a rowspan, then I want nth-child to add 1 to n and then continue." Mine is a bit more generic as in some rowspans that would work, but on other it wouldn't, depending on two things: if the rowspan has a even/odd value and it's tr is itself even or odd.