# How do you zebra striping a rowspan table?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

My table has rowspan cells, how can I apply striped background, so that the rows with rowspan cell are regarded as one row, like this:

[image]

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gtL0tL6f/

Comment: this is possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200997/how-to-use-nth-child-for-styling-with-a-table-with-rowspan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a pure CSS solution... But I was able to get the same effect using JavaScript.

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("td, th");
var groups = [];

for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++){
 if(tds[i].getAttribute('rowspan') != null){
   var rspan = tds[i];
   groups.push({
     parent: rspan.parentNode,
      height: rspan.getAttribute('rowspan')
    });
  }
}

var count = 0;
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
var dark = true;

debugger;
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
 var row = rows[i];
  var index = groupIndex(row);
  if(index != null && dark){
   var group = groups[index];
    var height = parseInt(group.height);
    for(var j = i; j < i + height; j++){
     rows[j].classList.add('dark');
    }
    i += height - 1;
    dark = !dark;
    continue;
  }
  if(dark){
   rows[i].classList.add('dark');
  }
  dark = !dark;
}

function groupIndex(element){
 for(var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++){
   var group = groups[i].parent;
    if(group == element){
     return i;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```css
.dark{
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<table width="200" border="1" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also here: https://jsfiddle.net/dotspencer/gtL0tL6f/15/

Answer (score 18):

You could build your table with many 
like:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>row a</td>
      <td>row b</td>
      <td>row c</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row b</td>
      <td>row c</td>
    <tr>
  <tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>row b</td>
      <td>row a</td>
      <td>row b</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row c</td>
      <td>row d</td>
    <tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

And your css could be

```
tbody:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

just like described in this snipepet:
https://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/KqoCs

Comment: clever hack! :)

Comment: Actually it's not even a hack, it was designed to be used that way. Best answer!

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the background in this fiddle to red to accentuate the difference...
https://jsfiddle.net/crx8Ldno/

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd) > td,
td[rowspan] {  
  background: #f00;
}
```

Comment: That's not what they're looking for. See example image in question above. Each row that starts with a rowspan cell needs to be counted as a grouped row.

Comment: That would be a lot more difficult

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the same effect by using jquery.

```js
var i=0;
var cols=$("table").find("tr:first").children().length;
if($("tr:first").find("[colspan]").attr("colspan")!=null){
      cols +=(parseInt($("tr:first").find("[colspan]").attr("colspan"))-1);
}
$("tr").each(function(index){
  var child=$(this).children().length;
  if($(this).find("[colspan]").attr("colspan")!=null){
      child +=(parseInt($(this).find("[colspan]").attr("colspan"))-1);
  }
  if(child>(cols-1)){
    if(i%2==0) $(this).addClass("mydark");
    i++;
  }else{
    $(this).addClass($(this).prev().attr("class"));
  }
});
```

```css
.mydark{
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="200" border="1" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```